# tabs navigation issue

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-tabs

I have tabs in the end of my page when I scroll down to the tabs and select one of them it takes me up to the top of my page the tabs work fine but I want to stay at the same part of the page when clicking on the tab I do not want to go up to the top each time.
this is my code for jquery tabs:

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <ul class="tabs">
   <li id="fixtures_tab"><a href="#fixtures"><?php echo ALL;?></a></li>
   <li id="live_tab"><a href="#live"><?php echo LIVE;?></a></li>
   <li id="finished_tab"><a href="#finished"><?php echo FINISHED;?></a></li>
   <li id="program_tab"><a href="#program"><?php echo PROGRAM;?></a></li>
   <li id="postpond_tab"><a href="#postpond"><?php echo POSTPOND;?></a></li>
   <li id="selected_tab"><a onclick="stripe_Color();" id='f' href="#fav"><?php echo SELECTED;?> (0)</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div class="tab-container">
 <div id="fixtures" class="tab-content">
     <script type="text/javascript">get_All_Today_Matches();</script>
 </div>
 <div id="live" class="tab-content"><script type="text/javascript"></script></div>
 <div id="finished" class="tab-content"><script type="text/javascript"></script></div>
 <div id="program" class="tab-content"><script type="text/javascript"></script></div>
 <div id="postpond" class="tab-content"><script type="text/javascript"></script></div>
 <div id="fav" class="tab-content"><script type="text/javascript"></script></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The jump is being caused by the anchor tags default action.  You an use jquery to bind to the `<a/>` tags and prevent the default action from being executed on click.  This is done by passing the event to the event handler and calling the `preventDefault` function on the event from within the handler.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tabs a").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/pDcHg/

[preventDefault Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: it does not work even i tried to use "live" instead of click and pass click as a parameter before the function but still not working

Comment: See the update, it should be wrapped in `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: i am sorry but still not working could it be because of ".click",i mean maybe there is another event i should use

Comment: @unique programmer Click is the right event, try adding an alert within the click event handler do you receive anything?

Answer (score 0):

use  `preventDefault()`..

it prevents the default behaviour of `<a>` tag

```
$(".tabs li a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: i tried this with and without doucument.ready but still not working